# Detecting a closed connection

Tags: grails, websocket

I have an Grails application which does the following:

When a request is received from the client side, the server starts creating a zip file for that request and sends it back to the client machine. The amount of time the server takes in order to create the zip file is very high, and even though the connection is lost between the client and the server, the zip file is generated by the server continuously for 3 days or so, using 100% of the CPU, and sending the response somewhere, probably a dead-end.

I tried looking out a way to resolve this, and I find that socket programming is a way in order to detect the connection loss.

This question may look broad, but I just want to know the ways, a connection loss can be found out, so that I can dig around that approach and find out the solution.

Comment: Provide the necessary info to replicate the problem or simulate your scenario and provide a solution.

Comment: If the application has registered users, allow them to start the job, then e-mail them to return, log back in, and collect the results.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the object holding the results of the `connect()` method is `null`.

You can also wrap a `try` `catch` statement around the code that attempts the connection, and print out the exception if it fails so you know where/what happened.